# Wamp Server - Asking for Password

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I have not used my Wamp server for a little while. I have just gone to http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php and it is asking for a password. I do not think I have a password.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panic over. Submit the details 'root' for username and nothing for password.

But I would still like to know why it did it when it has not done it before.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that happens if you have not turned on wampserver and you are trying to access the file. Try turning it on (making it online) before you access it.

I hope this helps.